# focus not disappearing when using .blur()

Tags: javascript, html, ajax, forms

I am saving a form using ajax. it only has one input and i have hidden the submit button. when the user presses enter button I want the input field no lose its focus. heres my current code: 
html:

```
    <form id="statusUpdate" action = "saveStatus.php" method="post" class="ajax"> 
        <input type="text" id="statusForm" name="status"  placeholder="<?php  
         if($status!=null){ echo '&lsquo;'.$status.'&rsquo;'; 
        } else { 
       echo 'Enter your status here.';}?>"> 
        <input type="submit" hidden="true"/>
        </form>
```

js

```
    $('form.ajax').on('submit', function() {

    var that = $(this),
url = that.attr('action'),
type = that.attr('method'),
data = {};

that.find('[name]').each(function(where, value) {
    var that = $(this),
        name = that.attr('name'),
        value = that.val();

        data[name] = value; 
});

$.ajax({
    url:url, 
    type:type,
    data: data,
    success: function(response){
        console.log(response);
    } 
});
return false;
$(name).blur();

});
```

currently the server side stuff all works fine so the database updates. However the on blur bit does not work. Any help to get the input to lose its focus after the user submits the form would be great.

Also on a side note I want it to run the ajax if they click off the input field so I have just copied and pasted the js and changed

```
    $('form.ajax').on('submit', function() {
```

to

```
    $('form.ajax').on('change', function() {
```

is there anyway to do a submit OR change?

Thanks very much!

Comment: Anything you write after `return` will not be executed.

Answer (score 0):

You are calling `.blur()` method after using `return` so the blur event is not fired.

try:

```
$('[' + name + ']').blur();
return false;
```

Comment: may need to be `$('['+name+']')` since `name` just contains the elements `name` attribute

Comment: hey thanks for your reply, I moved it as you said and now the ajax code doesn't run. so it goes to the page saveStatus.php.. any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

As for your second question, you can use:

```
$('form.ajax').on('submit change', function(){
    ...
});
```